# Jquery replace not worked with long text

Tags: jquery, replace

Jquery `.replace()` not worked with long text.
If you highlight a few words everything works,but if select all the text does not work.

```
//Grab selected text
function getSelectedText(){
    if(window.getSelection){
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    }
    else if(document.getSelection){
        return document.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.selection){
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
}

$("p").on("mouseup",function() {
    selection = getSelectedText();
});

$(".add-h1").on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(selection);
  if(selection.length >= 1) {
  var repl = '</p><h1>' + selection + '</h1><p>';
  $('body').html($('body').html().replace(selection, repl));
  selection = "";
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rd2d2/dPaDf/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't the length that is an issue but rather inconsistencies in spacing between the text returned by your selection and the text in the source returned by `html`.  For instance, in your raw HTML you have this:

```
fallback to users  JavaScript disabled
```

Notice that there are 2 spaces before `JavaScript`.  However, in the text returned by your selection, these spaces are normalized into a single space.

You will likely have similar issues with any other whitespace, line returns, etc. and certainly with any embedded html tags.  The text selection returns the text as it is seen, not as it was in the source markup.